# Enforce Snowflake Python driver to use a static port to receive token while using devcontainer

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, single-sign-on, vscode-devcontainer

I'm trying to connect to Snowflake using Python driver within a container [VS Code Remote Container plugin].

Here is `requirements.txt`:

```
pandas
numpy
sqlalchemy
jupyter
snowflake-connector-python[secure-local-storage,pandas]
```

Here is `devcontainer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "Python 3",
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
        "context": "..",
        "args": { 
            "VARIANT": "3.9",
            "NODE_VERSION": "lts/*"
        }
    },

    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "settings": { 
                "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/usr/local/bin/python",
                "python.linting.enabled": true,
                "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
                "python.formatting.autopep8Path": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/autopep8",
                "python.formatting.blackPath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/black",
                "python.formatting.yapfPath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/yapf",
                "python.linting.banditPath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/bandit",
                "python.linting.flake8Path": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/flake8",
                "python.linting.mypyPath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/mypy",
                "python.linting.pycodestylePath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/pycodestyle",
                "python.linting.pydocstylePath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/pydocstyle",
                "python.linting.pylintPath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/pylint"
            },
            "extensions": [
                "ms-python.python",
                "ms-python.vscode-pylance"
            ]
        }
    },

    "postCreateCommand": "pip3 install -r requirements.txt",
    "remoteUser": "vscode"
}
```

I set all parameters to open connection (with `authenticator=externalbrowser`)

```
import snowflake.connector

conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='...',
    account='...', 
    warehouse='...', 
    database='...', 
    role='...', 
    authenticator='externalbrowser')
```

Now VSCode is smart enough to open the browser. However, I realized using `"forwardPorts": [...]` is not useful because each time the driver is using a random port [to receive the token after SSO server redirects with token]. So browser fails to connect to `localhost:<some-random-port-here>`. Is there any way to enforce Snowflake driver to use static port -- to simplify port-forwarding?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it necessary to use Externalbrowser for authn and not OAuth which would obviate the need to have the port part, instead it would just need the jwt token for authn?